# Android: Listen for the Audio file deleted

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-file

I'm using android `MediaStore` to get the list of audio files on my music app and these files can be added to playlist. If the file gets deleted from the  device memory, the file information need to be deleted from playlist.

Is there any listener/receiver to listen when the audio files are deleted from the device internal/external memory?

I know we can use `FileObserver` for any file change. But this required a background service to always run and listen for the file changed. I want to avoid having a service for this. Is there any other way?

Comment: I have implemented something quite similar in one of my apps, i don't know if that is what you want. Basically I reload songs on every start in a list, and loop through playlists, queue etc. and find songs that are no longer in the list, and remove them. I know its not the best solution, but worked for me, because, the number of songs in an avg device are quite less, so reloading doesn't effect the performance much

Comment: @HarjotSinghOberai- Thanks . I do had similar approach , but this will slow down the app start , mainly in case all the songs are on the queue/playlist.

Comment: I had another approach in my mind, but never implemented it. Don't do anything on app start, but whenever, a song is played, check it path before setting the data source in MediaPlayer. If path does not exist,then you know, that the song has been deleted and thus skip to next song and in the background, remove the song from playlists or any other place where it has been listed

Comment: @Libin Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver for MediaScanner events, and refresh your list whenever you receive Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED intent.

```
IntentFilter scanFileReceiverFilter= new IntentFilter();
scanFileReceiverFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
scanFileReceiverFilter.addDataScheme("file");

BroadcastReceiver scanFileReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)) {
                Uri uri = intent.getData();
                String path = null;
                if (uri != null) {
                    path = uri.getPath();
                }
                //TODO:refresh list in path

            }
        }
    };
getActivity().registerReceiver(scanFileReceiver, scanFileReceiverFilter);
```

Any app which is deleting local data is expected to run Media scanner after changes, to sync the media DB, so you should receive this.

But this works only while your application is running. For background deleting, you should register one in manifest.

If you are using DB to store playlists entries, then this will be efficient as you can check all files with path LIKE path received for refreshing.

Please note that sometimes this event might be received late due to huge amount of content present in device.

You can also use ContentObserver calling registerContentObserver with uri MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external"). Since all Media Providers have Audio view, this should work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering ContentObserver with context.getContentResolver.registerContentObserver(args). I do this in onResume(). get current number of tracks in device memory. I do this in onCreate(). also get current number of tracks in the onchanged method of the ContentObserver in onResume(). If the figures don't match, refresh your current list. You can also register your ContentObserver in service for consistent results. Also don't forget to unregister ContentObserver in onPause() and onDestroy() using context.getContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(args). works like charm. I will post the code once I retrieve it. Happy coding!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).